# Bitwise saturated addition in C (HW)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, addition, saturation-arithmetic

I'm working on an assignment and I can't figure out how to implement this. I have to make a function `sadd(int x, int y)` that returns the numbers added together unless it overflows (then just return the max possible int). I've been able to come up with some solutions involving casting and conditional statements, but those aren't allowed in the solution. Only the operators `~ ! ^ + << >> &` and `|`.

Comment: Asking homework questions is ok, but you should tag them as homework.

Comment: Give it a try and post what you come up with.  (As Brian said, HW questions are fine but it's better to give it your best shot and post your code.  Welcome to SO!)

Comment: Without `if`/`else`, this is going to be hacky..

Comment: With a limited set of operations you could always brute-force a solution...

Comment: @Brendan: Similar questions are asked when the class is a computer architecture or similar advanced class.  Low-level instruction sets are restrictive.

Answer (score 6):

For addition of signed numbers, overflow has happened if you add two numbers of the same sign and get a result with a different sign. Because of the ranges involved, it is impossible to generate overflow when adding two numbers of different signs.

So, what you can do is — watching the sign bit only (the most significant one in two's complement) — use exclusive OR to get to whether the two original numbers differed in sign, complement that so that you've got '0' if they were different, '1' for the same.

You can then use exclusive OR on the result versus one of the inputs. That'll give '0' if they were the same, '1' if they were different.

And those two results together to get an overall '1' if the two inputs were the same but the result was different, '0' otherwise.

You can then use a combination of shifts and ORs to fill an entire integer with that value. Supposing you're in a 32 bit integer, just set the lowest 31 bits to get the highest value positive integer. What you can then do is a similar sets of shifts and ORs on the sign bit of either of the inputs. Exclusive OR the results. That'll instead give the lowest value integer if the inputs were negative.

EDIT: oh, and use the bit value of whether there was overflow, extended out to fill the int, to select what value to return by anding it with the result you would return if there were overflow, complementing it and anding it with the normal additive result, then oring (or adding) the two together.

Presto: all binary logic, no conditionals. I assume, because it's homework, that you don't want actual code?

---

Nine years later, I agree with the comment of @gman below; in order to implement saturating addition using only the permitted operators, you've got to rely on undefined behaviour — *and the answer above implicitly does so*.

A substantial risk with that is that compilers know which behaviour is undefined and may exploit that during optimisation. Knowledge of the underlying architecture (e.g. that it is two's complement, that it does signed shifts) is not sufficient to predict a compiler's output.

A robust production implementation is possible, but would require conditional statements and therefore would not answer this question.

Comment: I have this coded up; not sure if it's appropriate to add a full source answer on a homework question. Is the explanation I've given sufficiently clear?

Comment: Probably not, but hint him the length in instructions your solution takes (assuming the MIPS instruction set). We can play code-golf ;-)

Comment: This answer is wrong. The C standard, since the question is tagged [tag:c], [is undefined behavior for signed overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is). I wrote code that checked for overflow by checking for a change in sign. It failed once the compiler started taking advantage of the fact that overflow is undefined.

Comment: @gman do you believe it is possible to write a saturating add using only the operators the question specifies and not relying upon undefined behaviour? It’s the difference between changing the answer to say ‘you’ll have to rely on undefined behaviour’ or merely deleting it.

Comment: From everything I've read I'm guessing the answer is no it's not possible but maybe C/C++ expert would know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

From the ARM Website ([ARM Info Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359124210895.html)) on intrinsic functions:

> 4.1 Compiler intrinsics
>
> Compiler intrinsics are functions provided by the compiler. They enable you to easily incorporate domain-specific operations in C and C++ source code without resorting to complex implementations in assembly language.
> The C and C++ languages are suited to a wide variety of tasks but they do not provide in-built support for specific areas of application, for example, Digital Signal Processing (DSP).
> Within a given application domain, there is usually a range of domain-specific operations that have to be performed frequently. However, often these operations cannot be efficiently implemented in C or C++. A typical example is the saturated add of two 32-bit signed two’s complement integers, commonly used in DSP programming. The following example shows a C implementation of saturated add operation
>
> ```
> #include <limits.h>
> int L_add(const int a, const int b)
> {
>     int c;
>     c = a + b;         // Needs to be   c = a + (unsigned)b; to avoid UB
>     if (((a ^ b) & INT_MIN) == 0)
>     {
>         if ((c ^ a) & INT_MIN)
>         {
>             c = (a < 0) ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
>         }
>     }
>     return c;
> }
> ```

This example is unsafe in ISO C; signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour so you need to avoid causing it as part of detecting it.  `c = a + (unsigned)b;` would avoid the problem, giving the expected binary integer result because 2's complement addition is the same as unsigned binary, but in C `unsigned` types have well-defined wrapping.

Comment: `c = a + b;` is undefined behaviour if it overflows.  On a 2's complement machine, use `c = a + (unsigned)b;` to do the addition as unsigned and then implicitly convert back to signed. It's the same binary operation as 2's complement signed addition, but in C is guaranteed to wrap.