# Add 32-bit words with saturation

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, mmx, saturation-arithmetic

Do you know any way to add with saturation 32-bit signed words using MMX/SSE assembler instructions? I can find 8/16 bits versions but no 32-bit ones.

Comment: See [Agner Fog's vectorclass library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) for an implementation of add and subtract with C++ intrinsics.  A copy of the GPLed source [is here](https://github.com/pcordes/vectorclass/blob/77522287e64da5e887d69659e144d2caa5d3a4f1/vectori128.h#L2189), using XOR to check for same / different signs, and shifts / PANDN / PADDD to fix up the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate saturated signed adds by performing the following steps:

```c
int saturated_add(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + (unsigned)b;                // avoid signed-overflow UB
    if (a >= 0 && b >= 0)
        return sum > 0 ? sum : INT32_MAX;     // catch positive wraparound
    else if (a < 0 && b < 0)
        return sum > 0 ? INT32_MIN : sum;     // catch negative wraparound
    else
        return sum;                           // sum of pos + neg always fits
}
```

Unsigned, it's even simpler, see [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121240/saturating-addition-in-c)

In SSE2, the above maps to a sequence of parallel compares and AND/ANDN operations. No single operation is available in hardware, unfortunately.

Comment: [Bitwise saturated addition in C (HW)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277623) could probably vectorize better, with a couple `pxor` for `sum^a` and `sum^b`, and `pcmpgt(0, v)` or `psrad`

Answer (score 1):

Saturated unsigned subtraction is easy, because for `a -= b', we can do

```
    asm (
        "pmaxud %1, %0\n\t" // a = max (a,b)
        "psubd %1, %0" // a -= b
        : "+x" (a)
        : "xm" (b)
    );
```

with SSE.

I was looking for unsigned addition, but possibly, the only way is to transform to a saturated unsigned subtraction, perform it, and transform back. Same for signed variants.

EDIT: with unsigned addition, you get `min (a, ~b) + b` this way, which of course works. With signed addition and subtraction, you have two saturation boundaries, which makes things complicated.