# Add saturate 32-bit signed ints intrinsics?

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics, avx, saturation-arithmetic

Can someone recommend a fast way to add saturate 32-bit signed integers using Intel intrinsics (AVX, SSE4 ...) ?

I looked at the intrinsics guide and found `_mm256_adds_epi16` but this seems to only add 16-bit ints. I don't see anything similar for 32 bits. The other calls seem to wrap around.

Comment: as mentioned in [Is there a way to subtract packed unsigned doublewords, saturated, on x86, using MMX/SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56526082/995714) use `subus(a, b) == max(a, b) - b` with SSE4.1's `pmaxud`

Comment: @phuclv: This question is about *signed* saturation, which is a harder problem.  That link is useful for unsigned saturation, which looks similar but requires a different implementation.

Comment: See [Signed saturated add of 64-bit ints?](//stackoverflow.com/a/56531252) for scalar signed saturation with a GNU C builtin to detect signed overflow efficiently.  (Using integer flags; if it did auto-vectorize it would need more instructions.)

Answer (score 3):

A signed overflow will happen if (and only if):

- the signs of both inputs are the same, and
- the sign of the sum (when added with wrap-around) is different from the input

Using C-Operators: `overflow = ~(a^b) & (a^(a+b))`.

Also, if an overflow happens, the saturated result will have the same sign as either input. Using the `int_min = int_max+1` trick suggested by @PeterCordes, and assuming you have at least SSE4.1 (for `blendvps`) this can be implemented as:

```
__m128i __mm_adds_epi32( __m128i a, __m128i b )
{
    const __m128i int_max = _mm_set1_epi32( 0x7FFFFFFF );

    // normal result (possibly wraps around)
    __m128i res      = _mm_add_epi32( a, b );

    // If result saturates, it has the same sign as both a and b
    __m128i sign_bit = _mm_srli_epi32(a, 31); // shift sign to lowest bit
    __m128i saturated = _mm_add_epi32(int_max, sign_bit);

    // saturation happened if inputs do not have different signs, 
    // but sign of result is different:
    __m128i sign_xor  = _mm_xor_si128( a, b );
    __m128i overflow = _mm_andnot_si128(sign_xor, _mm_xor_si128(a,res));

    return _mm_castps_si128(_mm_blendv_ps( _mm_castsi128_ps( res ),
                                          _mm_castsi128_ps(saturated),
                                          _mm_castsi128_ps( overflow ) ) );
}
```

If your `blendvps` is as fast (or faster) than a shift and an addition (also considering port usage), you can of course just blend `int_min` and `int_max`, with the sign-bits of `a`.
Also, if you have only SSE2 or SSE3, you can replace the last blend by an arithmetic shift (of `overflow`) 31 bits to the right, and manual blending (using and/andnot/or).

And naturally, with AVX2 this can take `__m256i` variables instead of `__m128i` (should be very easy to rewrite).

**Addendum** If you know the sign of either `a` or `b` at compile-time, you can directly set `saturated` accordingly, and you can save both `_mm_xor_si128` calculations, i.e., `overflow` would be `_mm_andnot_si128(b, res)` for positive `a` and `_mm_andnot(res, b)` for negative `a` (with `res = a+b`).

Test case / demo: https://godbolt.org/z/v1bsc85nG

Comment: The other trick is that 2's complement `int_min = ~int_max`, so you can XOR with a compare result or with a `_mm_srai_epi32` result (to broadcast the sign bit) to flip max to min based on the sign of one of the inputs.  See [Signed saturated add of 64-bit ints?](//stackoverflow.com/a/56531252) for a non-vectorized C version using GNU C `__builtin_saddll_overflow` to get an overflow flag result from an `add` instruction, for a branch or cmov.

Comment: `blendvps` is great on Ryzen (single uop per lane even for the VEX encoding).  On Intel it's pretty bad (2p5) until Skylake, when the SSE version is 1 uop for any vector ALU (p015), and the VEX version is 2 uops (2p015) regardless of 128 vs. 256-bit.  But unlike FP shuffles, FP blends have extra bypass latency between integer vector operations like add, on SnB-family.  Still probably worth it vs. broadcasting the sign bit for `vpblendvb` integer byte-blend though.

Comment: You might want to use `b` as the input that determines the saturation value.  People are more likely to write `x = sadd(x, 123)` than `x = sadd(123, x)`, and a compile-time constant input lets the srli / add optimize away after inlining.

Comment: @PeterCordes Regarding the operand order: True, compilers (both clang and gcc) did figure out the value of `saturated`, but noticing that both xor-operations are redundant apparently is too difficult. I added a sentence about using possible compile-time knowledge (also works, if you know only the sign, but not the magnitude of one argument).

Comment: This doesn't pass my tests… `405785285 + 833772085` shouldn't saturate, but does.

Comment: @nemequ: Indeed, https://godbolt.org/z/cTWcK6GP8 has a test case.  Inputs that should saturate don't.  Reversing first 2 inputs to `_mm_blendv_ps` fixes the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/v1bsc85nG.  (I edited the answer to fix the bug.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version which works on SSE2, with improvements for SSE4.1 (`_mm_blendv_ps`), AVX-512VL (`_mm_ternarylogic_epi32`), and AVX-512DQ (`_mm_movepi32_mask`, on Peter Cordes' suggestion).

```c
__m128i __mm_adds_epi32( __m128i a, __m128i b) {
  const __m128i int_max = _mm_set1_epi32(INT32_MAX);

  /* normal result (possibly wraps around) */
  const __m128i res = _mm_add_epi32(a, b);

  /* If result saturates, it has the same sign as both a and b */
  const __m128i sign_bit = _mm_srli_epi32(a, 31); /* shift sign to lowest bit */

  #if defined(__AVX512VL__)
    const __m128i overflow = _mm_ternarylogic_epi32(a, b, res, 0x42);
  #else
    const __m128i sign_xor = _mm_xor_si128(a, b);
    const __m128i overflow = _mm_andnot_si128(sign_xor, _mm_xor_si128(a, res));
  #endif

  #if defined(__AVX512DQ__) && defined(__AVX512VL__)
    return _mm_mask_add_epi32(res, _mm_movepi32_mask(overflow), int_max, sign_bit);
  #else
    const __m128i saturated = _mm_add_epi32(int_max, sign_bit);

    #if defined(__SSE4_1__)
      return
        _mm_castps_si128(
          _mm_blendv_ps(
            _mm_castsi128_ps(res),
            _mm_castsi128_ps(saturated),
            _mm_castsi128_ps(overflow)
          )
        );
    #else
      const __m128i overflow_mask = _mm_srai_epi32(overflow, 31);
      return
        _mm_or_si128(
          _mm_and_si128(overflow_mask, saturated),
          _mm_andnot_si128(overflow_mask, res)
        );
    #endif
  #endif
}
```

I did this for [SIMDe](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde)'s implementation of the NEON `vqaddq_s32` (and the MSA `__msa_adds_s_b`); if you need other versions you should be able to adapt them from [simde/arm/neon/qadd.h](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/master/simde/arm/neon/qadd.h).  For 128-bit vectors, in addition to what SSE supports (8/16-bit, both signed and unsigned) there are:

- `vaddq_s32` (think `_mm_adds_epi32`)
- `vaddq_s64` (think `_mm_adds_epi64`)
- `vaddq_u32` (think `_mm_adds_epu32`)

`vaddq_u64` (think `_mm_adds_epu64`) is also present, but currently relies on vector extensions.  I could (and probably should) just port generated code to intrinsics, but TBH I'm not sure how to improve on it so I haven't bothered.

Comment: With AVX-512, it might be a win to replace the blend with a merge-masked `add` of INT32_MAX + `a>>31`, merging into `r`, using a mask from ternlog -> `_mm_movepi32_mask` ([`VPMPOVD2M`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovb2m:vpmovw2m:vpmovd2m:vpmovq2m)).  I guess that just trades a blend for a vec->mask instruction for throughput, but VEX-coded `blendvps` costs 2 uops.  As far as critical-path latency, a merge-masking `vpaddd xmm{k}, xmm, xmm` is 1 cycle latency with no extra bypass latency, but `vpmovd2m` has 3c latency.  (https://uops.info/).  With AVX1 vblendvps, there's ILP for the add.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking about with the add; the result of the vpternlogd already has the data necessary for a vpmovd2m. llvm-mca doesn't like substituting the blend with a vpmovd2m+vmovdqa32: https://godbolt.org/z/dq5YhhrGh. It passes my tests, but throughput is a bit worse (and requires AVX-512DQ instead of just AVX-512VL). Or are you thinking about something else?  Thanks for fixing the other version; I'll update my code to incorporate that soon since it's a little faster than what I have now.

Comment: I mean merge-masking `r = _mm_mask_add_epi32(r, d2m_saturated_mask,  _mm_srli_epi32(a, 31),     _mm_set1_epi32(INT32_MAX))` to only ever generate the saturated value in the elements that did saturate.  (That might need the mask inverted, which could be accomplished by `VPTESTNMD` with a mask if necessary.)

Comment: Ah, you're talking about in the original version.  In what I had posted both values were used when calculating the mask so that wouldn't work.  You're right, with that change it's slightly faster; I've updated my post with an updated version.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't looked at the details of how you computed the overflow condition, and hadn't noticed you just updated `a` instead of defining a new var.  Yeah, separating that is good for instruction-level parallelism, as well as saving uops by using the more efficient overflow detection.

Comment: Perhaps even better to use `INT_MAX ^ (a>>31)` arithmetic instead of logical right shift; some older CPUs (e.g. Intel before Skylake) can run `pxor` on more ports than `paddd`, so whatever surrounding port pressure can maybe be better balanced out. https://godbolt.org/z/Me8xdsbjj  Only downside is when AVX-512 is available, compilers failing to use EVEX `vpxord` with a dword broadcast memory source the way they do for `_mm_add_epi32`.  GCC uses qword, clang uses VEX-coded with a full 16-byte memory operand.

Answer (score 0):

This link answers this very question:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/285219

Here's an example implementation:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128i __inline __mm_adds_epi32( __m128i a, __m128i b )
{
    static __m128i int_min = _mm_set1_epi32( 0x80000000 );
    static __m128i int_max = _mm_set1_epi32( 0x7FFFFFFF );

    __m128i res      = _mm_add_epi32( a, b );
    __m128i sign_and = _mm_and_si128( a, b );
    __m128i sign_or  = _mm_or_si128( a, b );

    __m128i min_sat_mask = _mm_andnot_si128( res, sign_and );
    __m128i max_sat_mask = _mm_andnot_si128( sign_or, res );

    __m128 res_temp = _mm_blendv_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps( res ),
                                    _mm_castsi128_ps( int_min ),
                                    _mm_castsi128_ps( min_sat_mask ) );

    return _mm_castps_si128(_mm_blendv_ps( res_temp,
                                          _mm_castsi128_ps( int_max ),
                                          _mm_castsi128_ps( max_sat_mask ) ) );
}

void addSaturate(int32_t* bufferA, int32_t* bufferB, size_t numSamples)
{
    //
    // Load and add
    //
    __m128i* pSrc1 = (__m128i*)bufferA;
    __m128i* pSrc2 = (__m128i*)bufferB;

    for(int i=0; i<numSamples/4; ++i)
    {
        __m128i res = __mm_adds_epi32(*pSrc1, *pSrc2);
        _mm_store_si128(pSrc1, res);

        pSrc1++;
        pSrc2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably put a real example here since links only questions are not recommended (if page disappear or url has changed this make the answer useless...)

Comment: Sure. Will do after lunch ;)

Comment: `int_min = int_max + 1`, so this would be more efficient with `tmp = _mm_srli_epi32(a, 1)` and `_mm_add_epi32(max, tmp)` to select the saturation limit.  (A non-negative `a` can only overflow at the high end; even the most-negative `b` can't overflow that way.)