# Is there a way to subtract packed unsigned doublewords, saturated, on x86, using MMX/SSE?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, mmx, saturation-arithmetic

I've been looking at MMX/SSE and I am wondering. There are instructions for packed, saturated subtraction of unsigned bytes and words, but not doublewords.

Is there a way of doing what I want, or if not, why is there none?

Comment: You can use compare and mask. As to why it doesn't exist as a single instruction, it's anybody's guess.

Comment: I don't understand. How would I do that?

Comment: Are your source values signed or unsigned ? It’s fairly easy if the inputs are unsigned, slightly trickier if they are signed.

Comment: Check out how LLVM auto-vectorizes Rust  `u32.saturating_sub()`: https://godbolt.org/z/huP4PX  - range-shift to signed with PXOR, then PCMPGTD signed-compare, then AND/ANDN/OR to apply saturation to a PSUBD result.  I'm not sure this is optimal; it should just need PAND because the only saturation case for unsigned subtraction is saturation to 0.

Comment: You can use `subus(a, b) == max(a, b) - b` - E: well that's good with SSE4.1, does MMX/SSE mean literally only MMX and SSE?

Comment: @harold: oh yes, that's very good with SSE4.1 for `pmaxud`.

Comment: wow, these blow up my budget. i was asking my question, because i wanted to avoid cmp at all.PaulR unsigned, as stated in the Q. I guess SSE4 would be fine? I'd have to check. Peter, @harold thank you for your suggestions, i will look into the performance of these.

Comment: I don't know which of your commentswould be the best answer...

Comment: @z0rberg's The best solution depends on some context, e.g., do you care about throughput, latency, portability, etc.

Comment: @chtz throughput only. i haven't yet had the time to sit down with the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have SSE4.1 available, I don't think you can get better than using the `pmaxud`+`psubd` approach suggested by @harold. With AVX2, you can of course also use the corresponding 256bit variants.

```
__m128i subs_epu32_sse4(__m128i a, __m128i b){
    __m128i mx = _mm_max_epu32(a,b);
    return _mm_sub_epi32(mx, b);
}
```

Without SSE4.1, you need to compare both arguments in some way. Unfortunately, there is no `epu32` comparison (not before AVX512), but you can simulate one by first adding `0x80000000` (which is equivalent to xor-ing in this case) to both arguments:

```
__m128i cmpgt_epu32(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    const __m128i highest = _mm_set1_epi32(0x80000000);
    return _mm_cmpgt_epi32(_mm_xor_si128(a,highest),_mm_xor_si128(b,highest));
}

__m128i subs_epu32(__m128i a, __m128i b){
    __m128i not_saturated = cmpgt_epu32(a,b);
    return _mm_and_si128(not_saturated, _mm_sub_epi32(a,b));
}
```

In some cases, it *might* be better to replace the comparison by some bit-twiddling of the highest bit and broadcasting that to every bit using a shift (this replaces a `pcmpgtd` and three bit-logic operations (and having to load `0x80000000` at least once) by a `psrad` and five bit-logic operations):

```
__m128i subs_epu32_(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    __m128i r = _mm_sub_epi32(a,b);
    __m128i c = (~a & b) | (r & ~(a^b)); // works with gcc/clang. Replace by corresponding intrinsics, if necessary (note that `andnot` is a single instruction)
    return _mm_srai_epi32(c,31) & r;
}
```

Godbolt-Link, also including `adds_epu32` variants: https://godbolt.org/z/n4qaW1
Strangely, clang needs more register copies than gcc for the non-SSE4.1 variants. On the other hand, clang finds the `pmaxud` optimization for the `cmpgt_epu32` variant when compiled with SSE4.1: https://godbolt.org/z/3o5KCm