# Check if ax is divisible by 16

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, micro-optimization

How can we check if ax is divisible by 16?
I know we can by this command:

```
AND 0x000f
```

There is a faster command? (I think `idiv` is slower)

Comment: Bitwise logical operations are about the very fastest thing any CPU can do.

Comment: Thanks! There is maybe another way that is also faster?

Comment: AND is very fast on most processors. On which processor are you? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JérômeRichard To find another way that is also faster, there is another one?

Comment: I am thinking about SIMD instructions, but you may not be able to use them regarding what you try to solve.

Comment: I mean, you can also operate on other parts of the register, `and al, 0x0f` or `and eax, 0x0f` etc.  Those should be the same in terms of uops, latency, throughput, but could be very slightly faster/slower/larger/smaller depending on what mode you are in (16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit) and what the surrounding code looks like (dependencies).  You can also use `test` instead of `and` if you only care about flags and not the actual value of the low bits.

Comment: Depending on surrounding code (if the original value in `ax` is needed for something else later) `test ax,0x000F` might be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `and` is one of the fastest instructions, same throughput and latency as instructions like `add`, *much* faster than `idiv`<sup>1</sup>.  (https://uops.info/, https://agner.org/optimize/, [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-does-c-code-for-testing-the-collatz-conjecture-run-faster-than-hand-writte/40355466#40355466) (because the compiler used a shift instead of DIV.)

---

If you're going to branch on it, **`test al, 0x0f` / `jnz not_multiple_of_16` is even faster** on some CPUs (like AMD including Zen, or Intel Nehalem and earlier) that can macro-fuse TEST with JCC but not AND/JCC. [TEST](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test) is like AND but only sets FLAGS without writing the destination.  (So later reads of AX / EAX won't have the extra latency of AND in their path, and will be able to read the original value.)

Also, `test al, imm8` is only 2 bytes, saving code-size vs. 3-byte `and eax, 0xf` or 5-byte `test eax, 0xf`<sup>2</sup>.  (I'm assuming 32-bit or 64-bit mode; I didn't notice the AX in the title until after writing this, which hints that you might be optimizing for 16-bit mode.  Not a significant difference overall.)

If you want to modify the register value itself to actually modulo by 16, then yes use `and eax, 0xf`.  (Not `and al, 0xf`, you need to zero high bytes).  Otherwise leave EAX unmodified and just write FLAGS.

[Sandybridge-family can macro-fuse AND/JCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771526/x86-64-assembly-loop-conditions-and-out-of-order), but `and al, 0xf` would write AL, introducing partial-register stalls if you wanted to read EAX later on P6-family CPUs (Nehalem and earlier).  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)).  On SnB, RMW operations don't rename AL separately from EAX, so there's no later merging needed there, and it's not a *false* dependency because you explicitly want to test

If you want a 0 / 1 result in another register, then `test al, 0xf` / `setnz cl` is good.

```
  xor   ecx, ecx
  test  al, 0xf
  setnz cl              ; ECX =  bool(x % 16U)
```

(If you're using `setnz` or `cmovnz`, there's no advantage to `test` over `and`, except for leaving EAX unmodified.  Macro-fusion is only between test and conditional-branches, not setnz.  So if you want the modify the register as well, as creating a boolean, you can use `and` instead of `test` here.)

---

**Footnote 1: `idiv` is much slower,** and would need extra instructions to set up EDX, and put the divisor in another register, and doesn't set FLAGS according to the result in a useful way.  In fact, `div` and `idiv` are the slowest integer math instructions on most CPUs, with only other heavily-microcoded instructions like `int 0x80` or `syscall`, or for example a big `rep movsb` being slower.

Recent CPUs like Broadwell and later have fairly pretty high-performance HW division (https://uops.info/, https://agner.org/optimize/), and apparently Ice Lake improves it some more (especially for 64-bit operand-size), but compilers try *hard* to avoid division.  e.g. compilers will use multiple other instructions to implement `x / 10`, even for signed `int x` where that takes not just a multiplicative inverse for division but also some sign-bit handling to round towards 0 even for negative numbers.  [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)

**Of course for power-of-2 divisors, compilers know they can use AND.**

```
unsigned mod16(unsigned x) {
    return x % 16;
}

int mod16_signed(int x){
    return x % 16;            // negative for negative x, can't just use AND
}
```

[**asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVAB9LclIj2yAnjqVMtdAGFUrAK4BbWlwCcpU%2BgAyeWpgBydgEaYxCAAbKQADqhChEa0ljb2TuGR0XQeXr62AUGhepgGMQwEzMQEcXYOnM65%2BXSFxQRpPv6BIbpFJWUJlW31jRlZIQCUuqjWxMgcUta0UcBe6ADUthicwRDTs/ML4oMLAKQA7ABCezIAgguXC8SYBGO02/sATACsC6t7AMwn54cAIqczoDPAQlitghpNph0BAQdtBocfhcrjc7sQHuJnm8Pt9Af8pMNWNIXvIHLJ5KhpOYFkJRuNMM9Ppx5ARpHJBsMANYgbgHAB0B0cLxeBxeAA5Kgdgp8ZNxeESpNx5LYuDIZKQyXJSJSpPIhCB1azycM4LAYIgUKhbGE8OwyBQIGhrbaWshkKp1Jwnmq%2BLaCIF9RA/Gz5H5PMUAJ7SZmkJ22UwEADytFYUfJpCwtjUwHYIYzeBu%2BQAbph9enMOI8tZ/dH5CDMAqtaw8H5iJHLFg8wRiHgVVJmcN%2BIwWLmeHw6ARhGJJOmlE8VNmQFoNDpm359ZBhqgwoY6GWALSJz4Lfe2T5PE%2B2G7AMLFWxfP6fPUNvK7hwQVydCouMx9ZpBTgkiiN8v2UCJgJiP9MhaQDqjfOoOiscplDggp2gaTwmmggCekQ%2BJvyEdCoIGThhlpMYJi4QliVJPMdXEMVgn3YJuAWd1s3eJ4%2BRkbiFggXBCBIRlAIWSxnTtRknl2cwWRDDlSG5F5OD5IUxUFbgxQlUVODVeVpCVUgVW4F4%2BRlA4pUcRwnkcT4WKeMUNTo6Q9QNUgjXZUhTQtJ0bTtchKB8l0gmQYAdM%2BX1WH9YhA2DdMw1oSNa1jK143oZNUzzTNs1zdN8ELQwSzLLUKyrGt%2BzregGzzNc22ICMO0mLVu17WtBwnJg2A4MchynCQ8yUQCPU0bQVBbDcIC3HcYgPI9L3PS9r1vYh70%2BR9n30N8TDMUDANcYiYKAlJYiQrpDrffacNQ2p0J23QXxqWgEIw9J/xQm6ToIojMP6GCyLpSjSJUGjHPTejGOY1jgDdd4eOPfj8CIYhhNIUSrV8wJhOk2TjWoxVlRAF5uD5YIrKeGUZAOGRpRFcLNQpZzdFc9yCS5AmuO9OUnm4TgxRkMmSZeUIFSfEGtR1bH2Vxp5aNBhnmfkktopiHkgA%3D).  Compiled with clang and GCC `-O3 -m32 -mregparm=3` (so the first arg arrives in EAX, and is returned in EAX.)

```
# GCC and clang of course do this
mod16:
        and     eax, 15
        ret
```

But signed is harder:

```
# clang12.0 -O3 -m32 -mregparm=3
mod16_signed:
        lea     ecx, [eax + 15]
        test    eax, eax                 # set FLAGS from x
        cmovns  ecx, eax                 # ecx = !(x<0) ? x : x+15
        and     ecx, -16                 # round ecx down to a multiple of 16
        sub     eax, ecx                 # return  x - round_down(ecx)
        ret
```

Clang's has some instruction-level parallelism (LEA and TEST can run in parallel) and is probably best on modern CPUs with single-uop `cmov` (AMD, and Intel Broadwell and later).  GCC's has all 5 instructions dependent on the previous, so 5 cycle latency, vs. 4 for clang's.  Or also 5 on CPUs with 2-uop `cmov`.

GCC uses a somewhat different strategy, using cdq to broadcast the sign bit into EDX, then a right shift by 28 to get 0 or 0xf in EDX.

```
# gcc10.3 -O3 -m32 -mregparm=3
mod16_signed:
        cdq
        shr     edx, 28             # edx = (x>=0) ? 0 : 0xf
        add     eax, edx            # eax = (x>=0) ? x : x+15
        and     eax, 15
        sub     eax, edx            # if(x<0) eax++
        ret
```

---

**Footnote 2**:  [TEST](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test) doesn't have a `test r/m32, sign_extended_imm8` form, unlike all other immediate instructions that were part of original 8086.  It would rarely have been useful in original 8086, only for cases where you have the MSB set (so the upper half is all-ones) so you want to test if any bits are set *except* some in the low 8.  e.g. `test ax, -8` is like checking that `ax >> 3` is non-zero.

`x & 0 = 0,` so `test al, 1` is always the same as `test ax, 1`; it doesn't write the destination so only the FLAGS result matters.  And you can do `test ah, imm8` if you want, or `test ax, imm16` was only 1 extra byte in 16-bit mode so it wasn't a lot of missed savings when 8086 was designed.  It's a 3-byte difference for 32-bit operand-size, but modern CPUs often don't bottleneck on code fetch.

(Smaller is generally better to reduce overall L1i cache misses and usually pack better into the uop cache, and overall smaller binaries load from disk faster and have fewer iTLB misses, so compilers should favour smaller code *when all else is equal*.  Often not worth using slower instructions to save code size, and still worth unrolling hot loops a bit.)