# 8086 - loop over array using CX as index

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am writing .asm for 8086 using emu8086.

I want to loop over an array of bytes, using the `loop` instruction. Inside the loop I want to access the data in the array, **in order** (from the lowest memory address to the highest).

I can do it with the following code:

```
array               DB 9,1,4,7,2
length              DW 5

                    mov cx, length  ;cx <-- desired iterations
                    lea si, array   ;si <-- address of first array byte
my_loop:            mov al, [si]    ;load from array
                    
                    ;perform operations
                    ;on AL here
                    
                    inc si          ;si points to the next array element
                    loop my_loop
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it exploiting **just one register**, since CX and SI are basically doing the same job (the offset from the first array element stems naturally from the iteration count).

In this example at each iteration the values of CX and SI will be the following:

```
CX: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
SI: [array + 0, array + 1, array + 2, array + 3, array + 4]
```

Now at each iteration the value of SI is given by the formula `si = addr(array) + length - cx` where `array` and `length` are known at compile time.

Inside the loop this would look like (this syntax explains what I want to do but is most likely wrong):

```
mov al, offset(array) + length - cx
```

I am a newbie with addressing modes. Is there a way to avoid using SI altogether or can you explain why it's unavoidable to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> array               DB 9,1,4,7,2
> length              DW 5
> ```

> `array` and `length` are known at compile time.

There's a good reason to not define *length* as a memory-based variable, but rather as an equate by writing: `length equ $ - array`.

> I want to loop over an array of bytes, using the `loop` instruction.

If you insist on using `loop`, then you will have to use an additional register. On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086), the CX register can never be used in an addressing mode.

> I am a newbie with addressing modes, is there a way to avoid using SI altogether or can you explain why it's unavoidable to use it?

The SI register is not unavoidable, since on [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) you can replace it by BX, DI, and even BP. (BP is special because it uses the SS segment register by default, so don't use it as your first choice!)

> I am wondering if there is a better way to do it exploiting **just one register**

You can quite easily write the loop using a single address register (one of BX, SI, DI, or BP). Below are some methods:

```
  xor  bx, bx           ; 0
my_loop:
  mov  al, [array + bx]
  ...
  inc  bx               ; Increment the 'offset' BX
  cmp  bx, length       ; 5
  jb   my_loop          ; Loop for as long as BX below 5
```

and:

```
  mov  bx, OFFSET array
my_loop:
  mov  al, [bx]
  ...
  inc  bx               ; Increment the 'address' BX
  cmp  bx, OFFSET array + length
  jb   my_loop          ; Loop for as long as BX below (array + 5)
```

and as suggested by @ecm and @PeterCordes (shaving off an instruction):

```
  mov  bx, -length
my_loop:
  mov  al, [array + length + bx]
  ...
  inc  bx               ; Increment the 'offset' BX
  jnz  my_loop          ; Loop for as long as BX negative [-5,-1]
```

> Inside the loop I want to access the data in the array, **in order** (from the lowest memory address to the highest).

That's a pity (but not so much), because if it were allowable for the task at hand, you could reverse the direction and shave off an instruction:

```
  mov  bx, length - 1   ; 5 - 1
my_loop:
  mov  al, [array + bx]
  ...
  dec  bx               ; Decrement the 'offset' BX
  jge  my_loop          ; Loop for as long as BX positive [0,4]
```

Comment: The last example can be used with a negative index in `bx`: `mov bx, - length` then `mov al, [array + length + bx]` and finally `inc bx` \ `jnz my_loop` (Hope I didn't off-by-one, you should review that if you add it as an example.)

Comment: You can count an index *upward* towards zero, like `mov bx, -length` before the loop, and `mov al, [array + length + bx]` / `inc bx` / `jnz my_loop` to loop BX over the [-5, -1] range, indexing relative to the end of the array (array+length).  The `+length` in the addressing mode just folds into the absolute address so it doesn't cost extra.  Counting BX from `[-4, 0]` is a lot less obvious, but can be done with  `mov bx, -(length-1)` / `mov al, [array+length-1 + bx]` / `inc bx` / `jle top`.  I tested this and it works, but it's highly non-obvious that FLAGS set by `inc` are useful with `jle`.

Comment: @ecm: Great minds think alike :P

Comment: For counting BX down including zero, prefer `dec bx` / `jge` so it can macro-fuse on Sandybridge-family.  (*[x86\_64 - Assembly - loop conditions and out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31771526)*).  `dec`/`jns` can't fuse into a single uop but `dec`/`jge` can.  It runs the same on 8086, but `dec/jge` has no downsides there, so it's arguably a better idiom due to modern CPUs.  (Including Skylake; I just checked to make sure that hasn't changed.)

Comment: Great answer, very exaustive. I don't like many design choices made with 8086, like using cx as default for the loop instruction and forcing the user to either use jumps or using two registers

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza: The design intent of `loop` was for use with `lods` / `stos` for cases where `rep[n]e cmpsb` or `scasb`  or `rep movsb` / `stosb` didn't do exactly what was needed.  See Steve Morse's book, the 8086 Primer (for free on https://stevemorse.org/8086/).  (He pretty much single-handedly designed the 8086 instruction set.)

Comment: If you want other kinds of loops, don't use the `loop` instruction; [it's slow anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently) on recent CPUs. (It was good on 8086.)  Most ISAs don't have a special instruction for looping at all, it's totally normal to use `dec` / `jnz` or equivalent.  There's zero reason to jump through hoops in order to use the `loop` instruction for loops when you could just use a compare and branch at the bottom, or without the `cmp` if dec, sub, inc, or add can set FLAGS in a useful way.