# Saturating signed integer addition with only bitwise operators in C (HW)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, addition, saturation-arithmetic

For a homework assignment, I have to write a function in C that adds together two signed integers, but returns INT_MAX if there would be positive overflow and INT_MIN if there would be negative overflow. I have to follow very strict restrictions in what operators I can use. All integers are in two's complement form, right shifts are arithmetic, and the integer size is variable (I can find it with sizeof(int)<<3). I can't use contitionals, loops, comparison operators, or casting. I can only use bitwise and logical operators, addition and subtraction, equality tests, and the integer constants INT_MAX and INT_MIN.

I know that overflow can be detected if the two inputs have the same sign and the result has a different sign. I've gotten to the point where I have a flag showing if the equation did overflow. I have no idea how to get from there to the end product. This is what I have so far:

```
int saturating_add(int x, int y){
    int w = sizeof(int)<<3;
    int result = x+y;
    int signX = (x>>w-1)&0x01;//Sign bit of X
    int signY = (y>>w-1)&0x01;//Sign bit of Y
    int resultSign = (result>>w-1)&0x01; //Sign bit of result
    int canOverflow = ~(signX ^ signY); //If they're the same sign, they can overflow
    int didOverflow = (resultSign^signX)&canOverflow; //1 if input signs are same and result sign different, 0 otherwise

}
```

I'm trying to follow the answer shown at [Bitwise saturated addition in C (HW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277623/bitwise-saturated-addition-in-c-hw), but I'm stuck on the part where I have to fill an integer with the same bit for all but the sign bit (1 goes to 0111..11 and 0 goes to 0000.00). I have no idea what the "combination of shifts and ORs" would be.

Comment: Why the down vote?  This seems valid enough.

Comment: `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` is closer to portable, still assuming that `int` doesn't have any padding bits.  **`x+y` has signed-overflow undefined behaviour.**  Use `x + (unsigned)y` since you're assuming 2's complement anyway.  But anyway, this looks overcomplicated, and you don't want a 0/1 you normally want a mask.  See [Signed saturated add of 64-bit ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17580118) for more efficient code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the answer. What you should do is extend the sign bit to **all** of the bits, including the MSB. This can be accomplished by taking the int holding the sign bit, e.g. `didOverflow`, and add 1 to its complement.

Then you find which overflow value should be returned in the case that there is an overflow. That can be done by XORing `INT_MAX` with extended `signX` (or `signY`, both will work). Let's call this value `overflow`. Finally, alter `overflow` and `result` like this:

```
overflow := (extended didOverflow) AND overflow
result := (NOT (extended didOverflow)) AND result
```

Now, after these assignments, if the extended `didOverflow` is 1...1, then `overflow` will obviously remain unchanged. `result`, on the other hand, will be equal 0.

But if `didOverflow` is 0...0, then the opposite applies: `overflow` is now 0, while `result` remains unchanged.

In the first case (where `didOverflow` was 1...1, signaling that there was an overflow), `overflow OR result` equals `overflow`. In the second case (where we have no overflow), `overflow OR result` equals `result`. So either way, `overflow OR result` will give us the correct value.

Comment: Isn't a saturated add expected to return `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX` on overflow and not 0?